# How to show alone points, with {marker: {enabled: false}}?

Tags: highcharts

In my graphics i have many points and i set {marker: {enabled: false}} example

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false   
            }    
        }    
    },
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3Q9z/)

But, if graph points has nulls, all graph hidden.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/PWuTb/)

How to show alone points, with {marker: {enabled: false}} ?

Answer (score 0):

In case when you have null values, it means that "lines" between doesn't exist, and only markers remain. So when you disable marks, series in not visible.